# 16進数ダンプファイルの読み方

Tags: binary

アセンブラ学習の際にわからなくなりました。

> ASCII code 0x58 ('X') is stored at byte 0x2d

とのようなのですが

> xxd file.bin

をすると次のようになり、3行目の14byte目？に0x58があることまではわかります。

```
00000000: b40e b031 cd10 b02d cd10 b032 cd10 a02d  ...1...-...2...-
00000010: 00cd 10b0 33cd 10bb 2d00 81c3 007c 8a07  ....3...-....|..
00000020: cd10 b034 cd10 a02d 7ccd 10eb fe58 0000  ...4...-|....X..
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000060: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000080: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000090: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000100: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000110: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000120: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000130: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000140: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000150: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000160: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000170: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000180: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000190: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 55aa  ..............U.
```

しかしこれが

> 0x2d

にあるという意味がわかりません。このファイルはどのような読み方をすればいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

16 進法で数えて 2d バイト目に `0x58` があるということです。

左側に書かれている `00000020` などは、**16進法** でバイトを数えています。10 進法で数えて上から 3 行目左から 14 バイト目に `0x58` があるということは、16 進法で数えて最初から 2d バイト目に `0x58` があるということです。

Comment: なるほど！！ありがとうございます！